# Swift Realm delete Object error- write transaction

Tags: swift, realm

I am deleting a Realm object and am getting this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'

I have tried refresh()

```
extension Realm {
    func addWord(_ word: RelatedWord) {
        do {
            try self.write {
                self.add(word)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func deleteWord(_ word: RelatedWord) {
        BG {
            do {
                    self.beginWrite()
                    self.delete(word)
                    try self.commitWrite()
                    //self.refresh()
                } catch let error {
                 print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        self.refresh()
        }
    }
}

VC:
realm.delete(word)
```

Expected result:
swipe to delete object from tableview

Error: object deletion not being hnadled properly.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'

I think the issue is not with my function to delete a realm object but rather that there is an inconsistency between the Realm objects and the table view attempting to access deleted objects.

```
// Swipe to delete cell and word
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, view, completionHandler) in
    // Update data source when user taps action

    let letters = DataSingleton.shared.relatedArr.keys.sorted()
    if let data = DataSingleton.shared.relatedArr[letters[indexPath.section]]?.sorted(by: {$0.word < $1.word}) {
        let word = data[indexPath.row]
        print(word.word)
        self.realm.delete(word)


        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    completionHandler(true)
})
```

Comment: What is this `VC: realm.delete(word)`?

Comment: In my view controller I am deleting a realm object, it was called in the tableView function to delete upon swiping.

Comment: Right. That will cause an error. You should be calling .deleteWord, node .delete(word)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what BG is, but I would do it like this instead:

```
func deleteWord(_ word: RelatedWord) {
        do {
            try self.write {
                self.delete(word)
            } 
        } catch let error {
             print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    self.refresh()
}
```

Comment: I tried that and am still getting this error: 'RLMException', reason: 'Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'

Comment: I think I know what the issue is. In order to initiate a write transaction you need to declare an instance of a Realm. Here, `self` refers to the Realm object, not an instance of it. What you could do is use the deleteWord function inside your view controller rather than inside the Realm extension. Or else, you could try declaring a `let realm = Realm()`inside your extension and use it like this: `try realm.write { }`. I'm just not sure what the implications of doing that are, hence why I wouldn't use those functions inside the extension. Why don't you put them inside a helper class?

Comment: I don't believe the extension is the issue, as the extension has an add function which is working. My viewController contains var realm = try! Realm(), and the extension is an extension of realm.

Comment: I think I found your problem. Inside VC you have `realm.delete(word)` instead of `realm.deleteWord(word)`. So essentially, you are not using your custom function, you are using the realm delete function outside of a write transaction -- hence the error message.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thanks, I didn't notice that. The realm error is now gone.